# Audio playlist in QML

Tags: qt, audio, qml, qtquick2, playlist

I am making a simple playlist player on qml. I mean there is a `Audio` player which plays files with extension `.mp3` in a folder. But this "playlist player" assumes the whole folder as a playlist. So I give the path of the playlist folder as a command line argument to the program, for ex. `./playlist_player /home/user/playlist-folder` and program plays whole mp3s in the playlist-folder folder. But since qml does not understands wildchars like asterisk(*), I use `QDir` to find the names of the mp3s to find the names of the mp3s and expose those strings to qml by using an approach which described in here http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html. So I have an QObject-derived class names `FileNames` and it has `Q_PROPERTY(QStringList mp3List READ mp3List)`. So on the constructor of the `FileNames` I look for the path given in command line, and detect for files with extension .mp3s and push_back those paths to the `FileNames::mp3List`. And on `main.cpp`, I instantiate a `FileNames` object after that instantiate `QQuickView` object and I pass the `FileNames` object to Qml side with `QQmlContext::setContextProperty` member function.

Everything works until that I need also the number of the mp3s in the list to iterate all over with `next` function which increment `index` value for the list on qml side. I know I can expose another property for passing count of the `mp3List` but I ended up with this solution might not be the best native one.

Here is the code that I have wrote;

```
/* filenames.h */

class FileNames : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QStringList mp3List READ mp3List)
    Q_PROPERTY(int mp3ListCount READ mp3ListCount)
public:
    explicit FileNames(QObject *parent = 0);

    QStringList mp3List() const;
    int mp3ListCount() const;
private:
    QStringList m_mp3List;
    int m_mp3ListCount;
};

/* filenames.cpp */

FileNames::FileNames(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent), m_mp3ListCount(0)
{
    QString path("/home/user/music/");
    QDir dirname(path);
    QStringList dir = dirname.entryList();

    for (const auto &file : dir)
        if (file.endsWith(".mp3")) {
            m_mp3List.push_back("file://" + path + file);
            ++m_mp3ListCount;
        }
}

QStringList FileNames::mp3List() const
{
    return m_mp3List;
}

int FileNames::mp3ListCount() const
{
    return m_mp3ListCount;
}

/* main.cpp */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    FileNames names;

    QQuickView view;

    view.engine()->rootContext()->setContextProperty("names", &names);

    view.setSource(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///main.qml")));

    view.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);

    view.showFullScreen();

    return app.exec();
}

/* Playlist.qml */

Item {
    id: root

    property int index: 0
    property MediaPlayer mediaPlayer
    property variant list;
    property int listCount;

    function setIndex(i)
    {
        console.log("setting index to: " + i);
        index = i;
        if (index < 0 || index >= listCount) {
            index = 0;
            mediaPlayer.source = "";
        }
        mediaPlayer.source = list[index];
    }

    function next()
    {
        setIndex(index + 1);
    }

    function previous()
    {
        setIndex(index + 1);
    }

    Connections {
        target: root.mediaPlayer

        onStopped: {
            if (root.mediaPlayer.status == MediaPlayer.EndOfMedia)
            {
                root.next();
                root.mediaPlayer.play();
            }
        }
    }
}

/* main.qml */

Rectangle {
    id: root

    width: 1024
    height: 600

    color: "black"

    Playlist {

        id: playlist

        mediaPlayer: player

        list: names.mp3List
        listCount: names.mp3ListCount
    }

    MediaPlayer {
        id: player
    }

    VideoOutput {
        anchors.fill: parent

        source: player
    }
}
```

So does anyone has more native solution to making a "playlist_player" application with Qt?

UPDATE ->

So right now I am using `FolderListModel` but seems like this class does not work properly without a view. I guess because it works asynchronously. Here is how is my code look like;

```
/* Playlist.qml */
Item {
    id: root

    property int index: 0
    property MediaPlayer mediaPlayer
    property FolderListModel fm

    function setIndex(i)
    {
        index = i;
        console.log("setting index to: " + i);
        index %= fm.count;
        mediaPlayer.source = "file://" + fm.get(index, "filePath");
        console.log("setting source to: " + mediaPlayer.source);

    }

    function next()
    {
        setIndex(index + 1);
    }

    function previous()
    {
        setIndex(index + 1);
    }

    Connections {
        target: root.mediaPlayer

        onStopped: {
            if (root.mediaPlayer.status == MediaPlayer.EndOfMedia) {
                root.next();
                root.mediaPlayer.play();
            }
        }
    }
}

/* main.qml */
Rectangle {
    id: root
    width: 1024
    height: 600
    color: "black"

    property bool onStart: true

    Playlist {
        id: playlist
        mediaPlayer: player

        fm: FolderListModel {
            id: fm
            folder: "file:///home/user/music"
            showDirs: false
            showDotAndDotDot: false
            nameFilters: ["*.mp3"]
            property bool ready: count > 0
            // startup initialization;
            onReadyChanged: if (player.status == MediaPlayer.NoMedia) {
                                playlist.setIndex(0);
                                player.play();
                            }
        }
    }

    MediaPlayer { id: player }

    VideoOutput {
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: player
    }
}
```

Thank you,
Sina.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using C++ types in QML or defining context properties is perfectly fine when integration with C++ code is needed. C++ naturally extends the possibilities of QML and it is only a matter of understand when a C++ back-end class, or a newly QML type written in C++, is needed. For further discussion about this topic please have a look to [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33883960/2538363).

Given the answer linked above and the lifetime of your playlist component, using a QML-type instead of a context property would be the right choice. However, as said, QML already provide the right component for you: [`FolderListModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-folderlistmodel-folderlistmodel.html). In your case it can be easily defined like this:

```
FolderListModel {
    id: folderModel
    nameFilters: ["*.mp3"]
    showDirs: false
    folder: "file:" + /* CPP PROVIDED PATH */
}
```

and you can use [`get`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-folderlistmodel-folderlistmodel.html#get-method) function to query for the next mp3 in the list, according to the [`count`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-folderlistmodel-folderlistmodel.html#count-prop) property.

A great advantage is that `FolderListModel` *does* listen for file changes in your folder so that you *don't* need to check for file addition/removal. Last, but not least, `FolderListModel` can be easily integrated in a GUI implementation, using it as a model for a `ListView`. Please see [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-video-qmlvideofx-qml-qmlvideofx-filebrowser-qml.html) for an example.

### Addendum

As noted by OP the `FolderListModel` works asynchronously. That's a common behaviour since doing all the checks during component initialisation could lead to a long start-up (especially for directories full of files). There's no property to track when `FolderListModel` has finished tracking the filesystem, nor it probably makes sense to have one since the filesystem check is continuous. Adding a `bool` property could help, something like this:

```
FolderListModel {
    id: fm
    folder: "..."
    showDirs: false
    showDotAndDotDot: false
    nameFilters: ["*.mp3"]
    property bool ready: count > 0
}
```

When `ready` is true (because mp3s have been added or the initial scanning has finished) it could be possible to trigger the player. Clearly other properties can be added to improve the behaviour of the model.

Answer (score 0):

The [`FolderListModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-folderlistmodel-folderlistmodel.html#folder-prop) QML Type will do what you need. It supports name filtering, etc.