# How to Interact with a Qt C++ library inside a QML/QtQuick application?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I recently wrote a Qt based library to manage requests to TheMovieDB.org for a professional desktop application.

Not really experienced with QML and QtQuick, I think about migrating this application to QML which seems to be really adapted for.

I began few tutorials with QML...Amazing.
And now, I wonder if I can integrage my wrapper library into a QML application ?

Basically, let the user capture a movie name into a nice QML interface, froward the input parameters to the c++ wrapper, and retrieve the resulting json results + QPixmap object.

Is it something possible ?  I found some piece of codes to access QML components from a Qt c++ application but the inverse yet.
Or maybe am I thinking the things the wrong way ?

Have you ever wrote something similar, I mean regarding the interaction mechanism?

Comment: `Connections` type is a key point, take a look at it. Also, consider [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33883960/2538363) and all the links provided in it, especially the last part about context properties (which should perfectly fit in your case). Hope It helps.

Comment: My thoughts are a complete opposite. Context properties are evil, never use them. Implement classes in C++ that you can then use in the QML code. So, the C++ codebase is like a library of classes that are available to QML.